# React setState doesnt update the component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

i dont know why my react app wont update after i refresh the state.
I am displaying a table where the rows can be highlighted by clicking.
When flicking down on the touchscreen it should reload. The animation is displaying but the table isnt updating and the highlighting stays.

I provided a small code sample. If this post needs more code or information please feel free to comment.

Thanks in advance.

```
const dummyKonten = [
          { id: 1,
          icon: 'a',
          name: 'Sparkasse',
          isSelect: false },
          { id: 3,
          icon: 'b',
          name: 'Volksbank',
          isSelect: false }]

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      isRefreshing: false,
      konten: [...dummyKonten],
      updatedKonten: [...dummyKonten],
    };
  }

onRefresh = () => {
        const reset = [...this.state.konten];
        
        this.setState(
          {
            isRefreshing: true,
          }
        );
    
        wait(2000).then(() => {
        this.setState(
          { isRefreshing: false, 
          updatedKonten: reset } )}
        );
      }

selectItem = (item) => {
    item.isSelect = !item.isSelect;
    
    const index = this.state.updatedKonten.findIndex(
      indexItem => indexItem.id === item.id
    );
    
    const newKonten = [...this.state.updatedKonten];
    newKonten[index] = item;
    this.setState(
      {
        updatedKonten: newKonten,
      }
    );
  };

render(){ 
      return(
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.view}>
          <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
          <View style={styles.viewBody}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.updatedKonten}
            extraData={this.state.updatedKonten}
            renderItem={this.renderKonto}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.flatListItemSeparator}
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl colors={["#5797C5"]} refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing} onRefresh={this.onRefresh} />}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          />
          </View>
          <HomeButton navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </SafeAreaView>
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I think I see what may be occurring now. You really shouldn't ever *need* to use JSON to serialize/deserialize your data to clone it. You ought to avoid using this pattern in your production code.

I think the issue is a state mutation in your `selectItem` handler. If my guess is correct, `selectItem` callback is probably used by your item renderer `this.renderKonto`.

I suspect you are passing a reference to an `item` element from the `state.updatedKonten` state array, mutate it, and save it back into the array. The issue is that even though the `state.updatedKonten` is a new array reference, the item at `state.updatedKonten[index]` is the same old `item` object reference from before.

```
selectItem = (item) => {
  item.isSelect = !item.isSelect; // <-- (1) item mutation

  const index = this.state.updatedKonten.findIndex(
    indexItem => indexItem.id === item.id
  );

  const newKonten = [...this.state.updatedKonten];
  newKonten[index] = item; // <-- (2) 
  this.setState({
    updatedKonten: newKonten,
  });
};
```

Because of this React is likely bailing on rerendering the items since their object reference isn't changing.

## Solution

Basically update the `selectItem` handler to use a functional state update and shallow copy state and any nested state that is being updated. You can map the previous state to the next state array, and when the item id matches, shallow copy `item` and update the `isSelect` property.

```
selectItem = (item) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    updatedKonten: prevState.updatedKonten.map((itemEl) =>
      itemEl.id === item.id
        ? {
            ...itemEl,
            isSelect: !itemEl.isSelect
          }
        : itemEl
    )
  }));
};
```

Comment: I see. Thats a much better solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it.

The problem was the way i cloned the array in the state.
For this problem a **deep copy** of the array needed.
So i changed

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      isRefreshing: false,
      konten: [...dummyKonten],
      updatedKonten: [...dummyKonten],
    };
  }
```

to:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      isRefreshing: false,
      konten: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dummyKonten)),
      updatedKonten: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dummyKonten)),
    };
  }
```